# Passing data from controller to partial/view in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, faraday

Haven't worked with Ruby + RoR in a professional setting until now. Currently, I am passing `.env` variables onto the mounted react component as a prop and then making the GET request via axios on the client like so.

```
<%- cache(element_view) do -%>
  <%= element_view_for(element_view) do |el| -%>
    <div class="flex sm:flex-col">
      <div class="sm:w-full ns:w-full text-center">
        <%= react_component('element/SomeElement', {
          id: ENV["ID"], key: ENV["KEY"]
        }) %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <%- end %>
<%- end %>
```

But the team wants me to move the request into a backend service. This is what I currently have.

```
class SomeService
  API_URL = "someEndPoint"
  def initialize
    @response = get_reviews
  end

  def get_reviews
    conn = Faraday.new(url: "#{APIURL}/#{ENV["ID"]}/reviews?language=en&stars=5") do |faraday|
      faraday.headers["apikey"] = ENV["KEY"]
      faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
    end
    response = conn.get
    response.body
  end
end
```

I'm trying to use this service in a controller that looks like this

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @reviews = do_something
  end

  def do_something
    SomeService.new.initialize
  end
end
```

And I want to access the data on the partial like `<%= @reviews %>` but I can't seem to get any data back. I know the request works because I've tested it as a single ruby file. This may seem extremely non-descript but I did so for privacy sake. The code is probably a mess but please let me know if I need to add more details.

Comment: when is do_something called? what is get_trustpilot_reviews doing?

Comment: I fixed the typos but what I believe is happening (lol) is that `do_something` is calling the `initialize` method on a new instance of `SomeService` which is supposed to call the `get_reviews` method @AnaMaríaMartínezGómez

Comment: Get rid of `@response = ` and you also don't need the `.initialize`

Comment: @dan-klasson I got rid of the `@response` instance variable and removed `.initialize` but still nothing. Also haven't been getting any errors either so it's making me feel like I didn't wire everything up correctly?

Comment: @DylanNguyen I mean get rid of it in the service. Also, just use `pry` and debug where your problem is.

Comment: Try defining `get_reviews` directly in the controller, see if that works.

Comment: I can see `#{APIURL}` and `API_URL` constant, maybe this is the problem ?

Comment: I didn't understand the whole problem. You have two separate services or it's just one ror + react application?
If it's the latest, how do you launch the react component?

Comment: @DylanNguyen try to just render the API response in your view as text. If that works, you probably have to serialize it to JSON to pass it into your react component

Comment: Re: passing data to the partial, try:

`render 'my_review_partial', locals: { reviews: @reviews }` 

See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables